# Prove it is divisible by $abc$

Tags: number-theory

Let $a, b, c$ be real. Knowing that $a^3$ is divisible by $b, b^3$ is divisible by $c, c^3$ is divisible by $a$. Prove that $(a + b + c)^{13} $ is divisible by abc.

I didn't produce much, but I tried to expand it by making some substitutions, but it was going to be something extremely manly and certainly not the way.
I wanted something more elegant, I have no idea how ...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378977/prove-that-a-b-c13-is-divisible-by-abc-if-ba3-cb3-and-ac

Comment: Is this for some kind of competition? Lately popular.

Comment: Have a look at this site before posting:)